# How to use Jackson Annotations to process JSON with random object names

Tags: json, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "animals": {
        "113110": {
            "id": 113110,
            "name": "Dog",
            .....
        },
        "121853": {
            "id": 121853,
            "name": "Cat",
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, the JSON should be as follows and implementing Jackson annotations will be trivial:

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "id": 113110,
            "name": "Dog",
            .....
        },
        {
            "id": 121853,
            "name": "Cat",
            .....
        }
    ]
}
```

However, is there a way to use Jackson to abstract the object names so I can work with the original JSON, if anybody gets my meaning?

EDIT:

I do not know how to create my POJO. I could create an Animal class, with objects 113110 and 121853, but as these objects will always vary, how do I use Jackson annotations in my Animal class so that I can deserialize the JSON?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. What does it mean to "abstract the object names"?

Comment: Hi @toadzky, I've edited my original question. My main problem is that I do not know how to create my POJO.

Comment: I've a feeling @JsonAnySetter will help me, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all, but I couldn't really understand the rest of the answers ( I don't really want to delve into Jackson, I just want to convert it to a POJO), so I found an alternative solution.

I left out a key bit of information: The JSON I posted is part of a much larger JSON object.

I ended up using Jackson's @AnySetter as I noticed that any "un-parsable" JSON data related to "animals" could be retrieved in additionalProperties defined as follows in its parent class:

```
public class AnimalParent {

    @JsonIgnore
    private Animal animal;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = 
                                 new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Animal getAnimal() {
        return this.animal;
    }

    public void setAnimal(Animal animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Then in my main method where I parse the parent JSON, I have the following after the parsing is completed to parse the animals.

```
// start parsing parent JSON
...
// end parsing parent JSON

// parse animal
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

if (animalParent.getAdditionalProperties() != null) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> item : animalParent
        .getAdditionalProperties().entrySet()) {
        Animal animal = mapper.convertValue(item.getValue(), Animal.class);

    animalParent.setAnimal(animal);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is always a bit messy when your JSON is "dynamic" as per the OPs example. The main approaches are

- parse the JSON to some kind of dynamic `Map`-structure
- parse the JSON to a *tree*-structure (i.e. `JsonNode`)
- use a custom deserializer to parse the JSON and map it to a POJO

There are downsides to all of these approaches. The `Map`-approach offers no type safety and does not offer much functionality when it comes to traversing the object structure.

The `JsonNode` approach offers some nice type-methods and also some traversal methods. IMO this is a cleaner approach than the `Map`-approach.

The POJO-approach is type safe but a custom deserializer is required which is generally not pretty...

So, maybe the following "hybrid" approach can be of use.

```
// Setup the mapper
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Parse the json to a tree (JsonNode). This is IMO nicer than the
// Map since it exposes some nice methods for managing the
// underlying data
final JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

// Alt 1, use JsonNode directly
for (final JsonNode animal : json.path("animals")) {
    final int id = animal.get("id").asInt();
    final String name = animal.get("name").asText();

    // Do stuff with name and id...
}
```

If the `JsonNode` approach feels a bit too *raw* then it is possible to convert the `JsonNode` object to a POJO without the use of a deserializer. If you assume the following POJO:

```
public class Animal {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public Animal(@JsonProperty("id") final int id, @JsonProperty("name") final String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then, this code can be used for converting to POJOs:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

// Alt 2, convert to a Pojo
for (final JsonNode animal : json.path("animals")) {
    final Animal a = mapper.treeToValue(animal, Animal.class);

    // Handle the animal instance...
}
```

Finally, if the POJO still contains dynamic data you can use the following approach to handle that. In your POJO, declare the following:

```
private final Map<String, Object> dynamic = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnySetter
private void set(String name, Object value) {
    dynamic.put(name, value);
}
```

Note that it is not a must for the method to be `public` (i.e. it can be hidden from the *outside world*). This way you'll get hold of all the unknown/dynamic JSON elements.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, any time I'm dealing with weird JSON that doesn't map easily to POJOs, I just do custom serialization.

I would probably make the POJOs look something like this:

```
public class Animal
{
    String id;
    String name;
}

public class JsonThing
{
    List<Animal> animals;
}
```

Then I would implement a custom parser using the Jackson stream API. Here's a quick stub of a `JsonDeserializer<JsonThing>`:

```
public Stuff deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    .... // Start by creating a JsonThing instance and init the list.
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT)
    {
        jp.nextToken();
        switch (jp.getCurrentName())
        {
            case "animals":
            jp.nextToken(); // Skip to {
            jp.nextToken(); // Skip id field
            Animal a = jp.readValuesAs(Animal.class);
            // Add to list
         }
    }
    ..... // Return JsonThing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are not known in advance then use **Map** instead of POJO.

Have a look at [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133110/how-can-i-parse-json-from-webservice-result-with-gson/24134161#24134161) and [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199033/how-to-convert-json-string-to-map-dynamically/25199314#25199314)

You can try any one.

sample code: (using **Jackson Library**)

```
TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    Map<String, Object> data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("There might be some issue with the JSON string");
}
```

---

sample code: using [**GSON Library**](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's just a question of combining simple `Map`s with pojos? Like:

```
public class Wrapper {
  public Map<Long, Animal> animals;
}

public class Animal {
  public long id;
  public String name;
}
```

and that's it; although ids there match, maybe there is no need to try to model that dependency.